# Android App Query

Tags: java, android

Scenario: I am trying to use a MYSQL database which is associated with an instance of Moodle so that people with a Moodle account can login to the app. I have written a small app following a tutorial, however I am unsure of the error I might have possibly made.

Problem: When I run the app I am shown the login form; username, password and a button. Upon clicking it, but nothing happened.

PHP Code:

```
<?php

require_once 'include/config.php';

//Values
$username_in = $_POST['username'];
$password_in = $_POST['password'];

//Values Test
//$username_in = "guest"
//$password_in = $_POST['password'];


$query = "SELECT * from moodle_user where username ='".$username_in."' OR password = '".$password_in."'";
//TEST: $query = "SELECT * from moodle_user";
$query_exec = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

//if and else

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_exec);
if($rows == 0) {
    echo "No user found";
    mysqli_fetch_row ($con,$query);
} else {
    echo "Found user: " . $username_in;
}

    //Make your query and store it in $result

    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_exec))
    {
       echo $rows['username'];
    }


?>
```

Java:

```
package com.profiledt.helloworld;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button login;
EditText username, password;
TextView status;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setup();
}

private void setup() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greetingtext);
    login.setOnClickListener(this); 
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.login:

        login();

        break;
    }
    }

private void login() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://profiledt.co.uk/android/index.php"); 
    //  Adding Data:
        nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    //  Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side         variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username.getText().toString().trim()));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password.getText().toString().trim()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    // Execute HTTP Post Request
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);



        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        status.setText(""+response);
        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("No user found")) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPage.class));
        }


        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: you are going to have to use a different thread (try `AsyncTask()`) to do the networking code (`login()`). You should be getting a NetworkOnMainThread Exception.

Comment: Hi David, as it stands at the moment, I am having no exceptions. I have a few warnings with Hardcoded strings.

As for the AsyncTask, I'm confused about it's placement?

Comment: well, when you get the code working, you will see that exception. trust me. there are lots of examples of `AsyncTask()` out there (google it). Most folks put it as a private class within the calling class - the examples will make this clear.